# Formatter AxisLabel ECharts, Format label value

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I have used BAR chart from ECharts and now I want to format its Y-Axis value to some other value.

[image]

Right now EChart generated my chart like above, But I want to display its Y-Axis value instead of 30,000 or 60,000 I want to display it as 30K, 60K, 80K.., and 150K.

I have tried with Formatter but it's not calling function runtime while EChart generating a chart to convert the value, Looks like this way we can just add Prefix/Suffix to the value

```
yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      data: [],
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          show: true,
          color: "black",
         },
       },
       axisLabel: {
         formatter: '{value} K'
       }
    },
```

I have also tried to give the function in formatter but I didn't find a way to pass the current value as a parameter in this function.

```
yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value',
      data: [],
      axisLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          show: true,
          color: "black",
         },
       },
       axisLabel: {
         formatter: getFormattedValue(VALUE)
       }
    },
```

**UPDATED: WITH NEW TRY, BUT STILL IT's NOT WORKING**

When we use it like below on EChart official site then it's working
https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/release-note/5-3-0/#formatting-of-values-in-tooltip

```
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: val => `${val / 1000}K`
      }
```

[Updated chart with correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvpNZ.png)

But when I use it like below then it's not working, Even function is not getting called, the Value remain as it is

```
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: val => `${val / 1000}K`
      }
```

[Chart not getting updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53AZX.png)

Answer (score 3):

You are very close to the solution, actually...

```js
let option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    axisLabel: {
      formatter: val => `${val / 1000}K`
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [30000, 60000, 90000, 120000, 150000],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

The formatter is documented here: [Documentation - Apache ECharts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.axisLabel.formatter)

Comment: Hi, I am getting 
ERROR

src/app/components/common/bar-chart/bar-chart.component.ts:98:24 - error TS7006: Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type.

98             formatter: val => `${val / 1000}K`

Comment: This is because you are using TypeScript. Did you install type definitions for ECharts? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/echarts

Comment: Hi, Now I have installed your suggestion but still I am getting same error

Comment: I guess you are using a framework... Can you give me its name?

Comment: Yes, I am using Angular and it's version 14

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you try `(val: number) => ...` or `(val: any) => ...`?

Comment: I have tried with the above but as I said in the question this function is not getting called

Comment: Could you update your question with what you have tried, please? If you have a CodeSandbox or something like that, it would be ideal.

Comment: You can try it on this site https://echarts.apache.org/handbook/en/basics/release-note/5-3-0/#formatting-of-values-in-tooltip

If we use val => `${val / 1000}K` then it's working there but when we use it as (val: any) => `${val / 1000}K` then it's not working

I have updated the question as well, Please check

Comment: In fact, I am not sure to understand where you are stuck. If you want to test this chart with TypeScript, you should rather go to this page: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=mix-line-bar&lang=ts. There it works perfectly fine...